# Android layout folder on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed an app for Android and I need to run my app on different devices - especially on devices with 1280x720 and 480x800 resolutions.

Which layout folders do I have to create?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device/16910589#16910589

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout folder like this way.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

In Manifest add support-screens

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

For more info check this http://www.kandroid.org/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @developergg create another one layout folder like `layout-sw480dp`

Answer (score 1):

I recently finished my App and I did not use any of the screen size qualifiers, but instead I used the screen density and smallest width qualifiers:

```
layout/layout-land
layout-sw480dp/layout-sw480dp-land
layout-sw6000dp/layout-sw600dp-land
layout-sw720dp/layout-sw720dp-land
```

I also used dimens.xml files across the same folders above and mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi.

I am no expert..I am working with Android for about two months now, but this is the help I can give ;)

Answer (score 0):

layout not taken based on v19 or v1 version which taken base on device resolution :

```
layout             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
layout-large       // layout for large screen size
layout-xlarge      // layout for extra-large screen size
layout-xlarge-land // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

More detail Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @developergg,try to check device resolution and if possible then check such resolution with yourself.

Comment: Device resolution is 480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches (~233 ppi pixel density)
On emulator it's ok

Answer (score 0):

for **1280x720 (4.7 inch)** u need to create

```
res/layout-xhdpi/urxml

res/drawable-xhdpi/urresorces

values-xhdpi/dimens              //add dimensions
```

for **480 x 800 (4. inch)** u need to create

```
res/layout-hdpi/urxml

res/drawable-hdpi/urresorces

values-hdpi/dimens              //add dimensions
```

again for **480 x 800 (5.1 inch)** u need to create

```
res/layout-large-mdpi/urxml

res/drawable-large-mdpi/urresorces

values-large-mdpi/dimens              //add dimensions
```

and for more info refer my comment

**Links to restrict for specific devices**

[Restrict sales of an app by specific devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906988/restrict-sales-of-an-app-by-specific-devices)

[Android: Limit supported devices in Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636588/android-limit-supported-devices-in-android-market)