# different layouts for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created the different folders for multiple screens..

res/layout (for normal screens)
res/layout-large (for large screens)
res/layout-xlarge (for xhdpi screens)

when i have tested on grand 2 phone which is xhdpi, It takes the values from res/layout folder...

Is this a correct way to handle mutiple screen layout...and is there ant change I have to do in Android.manifest file??plz help me..thanks in advance..I have change the scrollbar size in two different layout...

res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"


    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>




        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style=" android:listViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout-xlarge

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"


    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>




        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style=" android:listViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142081/android-layout-folder-on-different-devices/27142152#27142152](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142081/android-layout-folder-on-different-devices/27142152#27142152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong saying "res/layout-xlarge (for xhdpi screens)". If you want to make different layouts attending to densities you should use hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi modifiers:

```
...
res/layout-hdpi ---> for HDPI screens.
res/layout-xxdpi ---> for XHDPI screens.
res/layout-xxhdpi ---> for XXHDPI screens.
...
```

large and xlarge modifiers were used (since Android 3.2 they are deprecated, meaning you should the modifiers above) to group devices in function of their size.

More information at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Layout folder like :

```
layout             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
layout-large       // layout for large screen size
layout-xlarge      // layout for extra-large screen size
layout-xlarge-land // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

add support-screens in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Ref. : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html