# How to adjust the app for different screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I created android app its working find and view of that app is perfect with my emulator,but when I install it in different devices layout or view is not showing properly,can any one give good suggestion for that,so that app can work same in all devices..

Comment: Check my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199591/different-layouts-for-multiple-screens/27199663#27199663

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana can you check my this question??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223915/how-to-get-alert-dialog-value-as-per-selection?noredirect=1#comment42926028_27223915

Comment: @HareshChhelana i added as per your answer it shows error, Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "android:resizeable".

Comment: `is perfect with my emulator`. Check your app against **multiple emulators**, each featuring different screen sizes and densities (and possibly, different API Levels, too).

Comment: @DerGolem i added support screen as per haresh's answer in my manifest but it shows error

Comment: Did you add `["true" | "false"]`?

Comment: My advice remains to create several emulators, at least **ldpi** (Yes!! If it looks good on a small screen, you on the right path), **mdpi** (the reference), **hdpi** (probably, the most used), **xhdpi**, **xxhdpi**. **xxxhdpi** is still not so much used.

Comment: @DerGolem yeah 
     <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>

Comment: That's why it doesn't work... **ROFL**!! You have to **choose between** `"true"` and `"false"`! It's **not** `["true"| "false"]`.

Comment: i dint get you,can you paste code ?

Comment: when you produce your app you must check that with so many screens and devices. You have drawable-hdpi ,drawable-mdpi and ... inorder to make your layouts compatible with all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Johnsan don't worry have not you ever set any property before?..here you can set either true or false...supports-screens android:resizeable="true" for more check this answer

[Optimizing Android manifest file for largest number of supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017627/optimizing-android-manifest-file-for-largest-number-of-supported-devices)